# MyBatis Performance of bulk operator

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have used MyBatis-spring + Java. I need to insert >10000 records into table in one transaction. To do it, I have used a mapper:

```
<insert id="saveBulk" parameterType="List">
    INSERT INTO "quote" ("id", "mi_id", "timestamp", "open", "close", "low", "high", "volume", "period")
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=",">
        ( #{item.key}, #{item.marketInstrumentKey}, #{item.timestamp}, #{item.open}, #{item.close}, #{item.low},
        #{item.high}, #{item.volume}, #{item.period}::quote_period)
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

And pass a List to this statement. It is worked extremely slowly for 2000-3000 records, but the 10000 records are inserted more than 4 minutes (I should increase the timeout interval)! The same 10000 records are inserted to the same DB via PgAdmin for less than 10 second. I tried to trace the processing  of this operation and found a bottleneck

```
public int doUpdate(MappedStatement ms, Object parameter) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Configuration configuration = ms.getConfiguration();
      StatementHandler handler = configuration.newStatementHandler(this, ms, parameter, RowBounds.DEFAULT, null, null);
      stmt = prepareStatement(handler, ms.getStatementLog());
      return handler.update(stmt);
    } finally {
      closeStatement(stmt);
    }
  }
```

The StatementHandler is calculated few minutes, and few minutes for prepareStatement. 
I understand, why it happens: 10000 records with 9 field for each record. All these 100k fields should be inserted as parameters into statement.
And how can I accelerate this process?

UPDATE:

I implements a batch save with using of "BATCH" mode of sqlFactory and @Transactional. 
This is configuration of mybatis-spring XML config:

```
    <bean id="sqlBatchTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="BATCH"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="quoteBatchMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="tafm.dataaccess.mybatis.mapper.QuoteMapper"/>
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
        <property name="sqlSessionTemplate" ref="sqlBatchTemplate"/>
    </bean>
   <bean id="dataAccessBatch" class="tafm.dataaccess.DataAccess">
        <property name="quoteMapper" ref="quoteBatchMapper"/>
    </bean>
```

Then, I have implemented a "batch" method:

```
   @Transactional
    public void saveBulk(List<Quote> quotes) {


        for(Quote q:quotes) {
            mapper.save(q);
        }
    }
```

**mapper** - is XML mapper for entity Quote:

```
<insert id="saveBulk" parameterType="List">
    INSERT INTO "quote" ("id", "mi_id", "timestamp", "open", "close", "low", "high", "volume", "period")
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=",">
        ( #{item.key}, #{item.marketInstrumentKey}, #{item.timestamp}, #{item.open}, #{item.close}, #{item.low},
        #{item.high}, #{item.volume}, #{item.period}::quote_period)
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

It is working fast

Comment: please tell me which database server you are using ?

Comment: I have used PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: please try below method.may be it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this.
**Mapper.xml**

```
<insert id="saveBulk" parameterType="List">
    INSERT INTO "quote" ("id", "mi_id", "timestamp", "open", "close", "low", "high", "volume", "period")
    VALUES
    <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=",">
        ( #{item.key}, #{item.marketInstrumentKey}, #{item.timestamp}, #{item.open}, #{item.close}, #{item.low},
        #{item.high}, #{item.volume}, #{item.period}::quote_period)
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

**In Java File**

```
public void insertBulkData(List<Item> list)
    {
        int total = list.size();        
        int interval = 1000;
        int from = 0;
        int to = 0;
        while (to <= total)
        {
            from = to == 0 ? 0 : to;
            to = (to + interval) <= total ? (to + interval) : total;
            saveBulk(list.subList(from, to));
            if (to == total)
                break;
        }
    }
```

above code using interval at 1000.so 1000 records will insert at a time.you can modify this interval also.
you have to call **insertBulkData(list)**.

I hope this will helpful  to you.

Comment: Thank you. This trick does resolve this particular problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the main problem: performance. So, I don't recommend to use this approach for real bulk insert (thousand records). I can recommend to use a Batch execution type instead of this approach

Comment: I have added section "UPDATE" to my initial question. I tried to clarify, how to implement batch mode